# Firebase Cloud Function not setting new document

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

When a user sign's up in my app, there is a Firebase cloud function that will store `authUid` and `emailAddress` in a `temporaryUsers` collection until the user verify's his email address. Once verified, the cloud function will create a new document in a `users` collection and delete the user's temporary document in the `temporaryUsers` collection.

Everything works good (the temporary doc is rightly deleted after verification) **with the exception of the *user document* NOT being created in the `users` collection. For some reason this document is not being created.**

Perhaps someone has tips on how I can better do error checking in this cloud function? Or, anyone spot any issues/errors in my code? Here is the cloud function (with some log details below):

> `confirmEmail.js`

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

export const confirmEmail = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const confirmationHash = req.query.conf
  const auth = admin.auth()
  const store = admin.firestore()

  const querySnapshot = await store
    .collection('temporaryUsers')
    .where('confirmationHash', '==', confirmationHash)
    .get()

  // redirect user to email confirmation failure route if failure
  if (querySnapshot.size === 0) {
    return res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/email-confirmation/failure')
  }

  // else get the temporaryuser doc
  const temporaryUserDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0]
  // grab properties we want from the temporary user doc
  const { authUid, emailAddress, displayName } = temporaryUserDoc.data()

  // update our user's Firebase Auth account and set the email verified property to true
  await auth.updateUser(authUid, { emailVerified: true })
  // add verified user to users collection
  try {
    const docRef = await store.collection('users').doc(authUid).set({
      emailAddress,
      displayName
    })
    console.log('doc updated!', docRef)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error in updating user', error)
  }

  // after user verified, delete temporary user doc 
  await store.collection('temporaryUsers').doc(temporaryUserDoc.id).delete()
  // redirect user to success page after successful verification
  // return res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/email-confirmation/success')
  // TO DO: redirect user to success page and then have them login again
  return res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/')
})
```

> Logs:

```
5:53:42.241 AM
confirmEmail
Function execution took 4824 ms, finished with status code: 302
5:53:37.418 AM
confirmEmail
Function execution started
5:52:49.984 AM
sendVerificationEmail
Function execution took 3400 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
5:52:49.981 AM
sendVerificationEmail
it works
5:52:46.585 AM
sendVerificationEmail
Function execution started
5:52:45.389 AM
createAccount
Function execution took 4568 ms, finished with status code: 200
5:52:43.796 AM
createAccount
}
5:52:43.796 AM
createAccount
createdAt: 1609242763793
5:52:43.796 AM
createAccount
confirmationHash: '38563d53-be8e-4402-8f21-fb0260e3d7d4',
5:52:43.796 AM
createAccount
emailAddress: 'redacted@gmail.com',
5:52:43.796 AM
createAccount
displayName: 'doss',
5:52:43.796 AM
createAccount
authUid: 'EMUxT8qYz4SJJqKILHt0QU70iZy2',
5:52:43.796 AM
createAccount
tempUserInfo from createTemporaryUserJs: {
5:52:40.822 AM
createAccount
Function execution started
5:52:40.747 AM
createAccount
Function execution took 13 ms, finished with status code: 204
5:52:40.735 AM
createAccount
Function execution started
```

Additional logs after adding try/catch to `confirmEmail.js`:

[image]

Comment: "Perhaps someone has tips on how I can better do error checking in this cloud function" => use `try/catch` and `console.log()`. I cannot see any problem in your code at first sight. Are you sure that `authUid` has the correct value?

Comment: Let me investigate and get back. Thx!

Comment: @RenaudTarnec: I added a try/catch (see edited code above) and only thing I see now in the logs is: `doc updated! WriteResult { _writeTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1609255658, _nanoseconds: 835622000 } ` . No new user document added to `users` collection either.

Comment: I figured it out. It was a missing parameter that I needed to carry over from temp folder to user folder. Will update my question with an answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was a mistake on my part. I was watching the firebase firestore console and filtering the data by the `createdAt` property....but the new data was not showing up because my `confirmEmail.js` function did not have the `createdAt` property added to this:

```
    const docRef = await store.collection('users').doc(authUid).set({
      emailAddress,
      displayName,
      createdAt <---- i forgot this 
    })
```

Now that it does, I do see the new verified user in the `users` collection and all is well with the world.